# MySQL Create Table Error 1064

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to create a table in MySQL but it doesn't want to play:

```
create table traders(
    traderID INT(9) ZEROFILL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNSIGNED,
    traderProfileName VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    traderPassword CHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    traderFirstName VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    traderSurname VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    traderContactPhone VARCHAR(14) NOT NULL,
    locationPostCode CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
    traderEmail VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
    traderBio VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    traderReviewRating DECIMAL(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
    traderLastLogin DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY_KEY(traderID)
);
```

And I am getting error:

```
"ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNSIGNED,
traderProfileName VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
traderPassword CHAR(128) NOT ' at line 2"
```

Is this something simple as I am using incorrect parameters for the table settings?

Comment: also `unsigned` is not a valid mysql type. Read the manual ! You have an invalid type and a typo.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `UNSIGNED` you must put it right beside the data type, that is: `INT UNSIGNED`.

Your corrected `CREATE` statement should look like this:

```
create table traders(
    traderID INT(9) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
--           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Here is the problem.
--  Also, you can define this column as a primary key +---^^^^^^^^^^^
--  directly in the column definition                 |
    traderProfileName VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    traderPassword CHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    traderFirstName VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    traderSurname VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    traderContactPhone VARCHAR(14) NOT NULL,
    locationPostCode CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
    traderEmail VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
    traderBio VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    traderReviewRating DECIMAL(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
    traderLastLogin DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
);
```

You may ask, "Why?" that's because there are *two* "types" of integer:

- `INT` signed (which can store values from -2147483648 to 2147483647)
- `INT UNSIGNED` (which can store values from 0 to 4294967295)

Reference:

- [MySQL reference: Data types > Numeric types > Integer types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html)

Comment: One more thing... `ZEROFILL` will only make your values to be displayed with leading zeros, it won't affect how the values are stored (i.e. `123` is the same as `000000123`)... is it really important to have those leading zeros?

Answer (score 0):

Auto increment is an integer by default, no need to define unsigned.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: What if he wants the column to be `UNSIGNED` integer?

Comment: If you don't define the column as `INT UNSIGNED` (i.e. just `INT`) the greatest value it can store will be 2147483647; if you define it as `INT UNSIGNED` the greatest value it can store will be 4294967295. [See here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  create table traders
(
traderID INT(9) ZEROFILL NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
traderProfileName VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
traderPassword CHAR(128) NOT NULL,
traderFirstName VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
traderSurname VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
traderContactPhone VARCHAR(14) NOT NULL,
locationPostCode CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
traderEmail VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
traderBio VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
traderReviewRating DECIMAL(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
traderLastLogin DATETIME DEFAULT NULL
);
```

- no need for unsigned
- use primary key in same line as trader(id)

[here working demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f3a17)

Comment: If the table is meant to hold more than 2147483647 rows, shouldn't it be declared as `INT UNSIGNED`? I know that's a lot, but it may happen

Answer (score -1):

You have some MySQL syntax errors. Here's the fix:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `traders` (
`traderID` INT(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`traderProfileName` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
`traderPassword` CHAR(128) NOT NULL,
`traderFirstName` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
`traderSurname` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
`traderContactPhone` VARCHAR(14) NOT NULL,
`locationPostCode` CHAR(4) NOT NULL,
`traderEmail` VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL,
`traderBio` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`traderReviewRating` DECIMAL(5,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`traderLastLogin` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`traderID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

I would add the preferred engine, charset, collation and auto increment start number.
If you'd like to do so just substitute the last line with:

```
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

And modify as desired.
Otherwise leave the closing parenthesis.

```
);
```

Comment: An explanation of what you changed would be helpful.